# Table rows to be uneditable

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am using a react table wherein I store values based  on inputs to the text fields. However the problem is that the table rows are editable. I want to make it fixed. I am using input in table data to add all the properties required. I am using material-ui core and bootstrap for the table.

Here is my code:

```
export class KPIDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [],
    idx: []
  };
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

  handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  //2
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      KPI_Before: "",
      UOM_Before: "",
      Base_Before: "",
      Target_Before: "",
      dateTime: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  //3
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  setDate = dateTime => this.setState({ dateTime });

  deleteRow = index => {
    var rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ rows });
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    const {
      values: {
        Title,
        Details,
        What,
        Why,
        How,
        Status,
        Cost,
        Benefits,
        Kpi_Before,
        Kpi_After,
        UOM_Before,
        Base_Before,
        Target_Before,
        Time,
        dateTime
      }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                  gutterBottom
                  align="center"
                  style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  KPI Before Implementation
                </Typography>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <TextField
                label="KPI"
                id="Kpi_Before"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                placeholder="Enter the KPI"
                onChange={handleChange("Kpi_Before")}
                defaultValue={values.Kpi_Before}
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
                <InputLabel
                  htmlFor="UOM_Before"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    top: "50%",
                    transform: "translate(0,-50%"
                  }}
                >
                  UOM
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="UOM_Before"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={handleChange("UOM_Before")}
                  defaultValue={values.UOM_Before}
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputProps={{
                    id: "UOM_Before"
                  }}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="Nos">Nos</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Percentage">Percentage</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Metric">Metric</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

    <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                  <table
                    className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                    id="tab_logic"
                  >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                        <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                          <td>{idx}</td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Kpi_Before"
                              defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="UOM_Before"
                              defaultValue={UOM_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Base_Before"
                              defaultValue={Base_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={Target_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={dateTime}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <MuiThemeProvider theme={redTheme}>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this)}
                                variant="outlined"
                                index={idx}
                                color="primary"
                                size="small"
                                style={styles.button}
                              >
                                -
                              </Button>
                            </MuiThemeProvider>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>



          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

          <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="left"
            alignItems="left"
            style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              onClick={this.continue}
              style={{ marginLeft: "10%" }}
              style={styles.button}
            >
              Continue
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="default"
              size="small"
              style={styles.button}
              onClick={this.back}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: purple
  },
  status: {
    danger: "orange"
  }
});

const styles = {
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    verticalAlign: "bottom"
  }
};

export default KPIDetails;
```

this the code for the table: I have used material-ui core for the project but have used a bootstrap table here

```
<Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                  <table
                    className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                    id="tab_logic"
                  >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                        <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                          <td>{idx}</td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Kpi_Before"
                              defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="UOM_Before"
                              defaultValue={UOM_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Base_Before"
                              defaultValue={Base_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={Target_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={dateTime}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <MuiThemeProvider theme={redTheme}>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this)}
                                variant="outlined"
                                index={idx}
                                color="primary"
                                size="small"
                                style={styles.button}
                              >
                                -
                              </Button>
                            </MuiThemeProvider>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys got the answer made the input field read only